# bash read file with a path gives error: No such file or directory

Tags: bash

So I am trying to read each line of a file but it gives me an error.

> No such file or directory

But the file does exist

here is the code:

```
echo the file path is $pathToGo
while read p
do 
    echo $p
done < $pathToGo
```

output:

[image: error image]

Now if I hard code the path it works just fine:

```
pathToGo="C:\Users\sorel\Bash\CW3\4\files\indexFiles\3346"
echo the file path is $pathToGo
while read p
do 
    echo $p
done < $pathToGo
```

I have also tried this code on a Linux machine, with a different path, and the same error is showing...

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your script has dos line endings. Remove them.

Comment: We know this because the error message has the colon at the start of the line. A "normal" bash error message looks like `bash: /some/file: No such file or directory` -- the "hidden" carriage return at the end of the contents of `$pathToGo` returns the cursor to the start of the line for the `: No such file...` part of the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have changed my source code to Unix (LF) with notepad++.  But the error remains. Any suggestion on how to remove the dos line ending? Thanks again.

Comment: Going forward, please try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance.

Comment: You don't show where the variable `pathToGo` gets into your script, so we can't say how the carriage return got into it. A [mre] needs to be complete enough to reproduce the problem described.

Comment: @Augustin Where is the variable `pathToGo` coming from? If it's read from some other file, that file may have DOS/Windows line endings.

Comment: the pathToGo is coming from a windows .txt file... I switched the EOL of the .txt with notepad++. Now it is working perfectly fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try below : I just added -r option .

```
echo the file path is $pathToGo
while read -r p
do 
    echo $p
done < $pathToGo
```

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Comment: It's not sufficient, but a necessary partial fix.